# Creating subdomain with Vesta CP and DigitalOcean

Tags: dns, subdomain, digital-ocean

I'm trying to configure but everytime I access domain.mysite.com.br keeps showing me the not found error.
www.mysite.com.br is redirecting me correct. Only the subdomain is not.

This is my vesta configurations:
[image: This is my vesta configurations]

Digital ocean DNS configuration
[image: Digital ocean DNS configuration]

My ftp is showing the new subdomain folder correctly
[image: My ftp is showing the new subdomain folder correctly]

Am I configuring Digital Ocean DNS wrong?
OBS: My server IP is not 111.111.1.111, I edited in Photoshop for security.

Sorry, my English is not good.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a subdomain in vesta cp with the following steps :

- Create DNS Record for your domain (maisrp.com.br) on vestacp menu, the type of record is CNAME that pointed to your droplet IP address. Enter subdomain that you want to add on record section (i.e mysubdomain)

[image: Create DNS Record for your subdomain]

- Add a new domain through Vesta Cp with full address (i.e mysubdomain.maisrp.com.br)

[image: Add new domain]

I have tried this, and work

Comment: This is beyond science.

Answer (score 0):

In VestaCp **Ver: 1.0.0** how to do it for properly work? OK...

In your primary `<domain.com>` set alias:

- `mail.<domain.com>`
- `pop.<domain.com>`
- or others what you want...

**remove** `*.<domain.com>` this colapse your subdomain (you can't run php or show html...)

Create subdomain: `subdomain.<domain.com>` and apply separatly Let's SSL or manually copy and paste Wild cert from primary settings in three text inputs.

Subdomain Alias: `www.subdomain.<domain.com>`

If you use php in primary domain set apache as `default` and nginx `default` too. In your subdomain you can set custom settings `PHP-CGI`, `PHP-CLI`...

Regards

Answer (score -1):

It worked! I just waited for 15 minutes and it worked. I thought it was instantaneous, but its not. Now subdomain.mysite.com.br is working, but www.subdomain.mysite.com.br is not :/ why?

Comment: Because you need to add A record which point on `www.subdomain.mysite.com.br` to the same IP address which is used in A record point on `subdomain.mysite.com.br`.